# How to create a check (Table A.Id and Table B.Id and TypeId = 1)?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need a relationship between a contract (CompanyId) and a company (CompanyId) with a company type is equal to 1.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Contract]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Contract_Company] FOREIGN KEY([CompanyId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Company] ([CompanyId]) WHERE CompanyTypeId = 1
```

Comment: Do the SMART guy (who give me -1) give me the answer? Else how could you give me -1, if you did not give me the answer. Thanks for helping me...

Comment: -1 is for a poorly written question or a question that doesn't show much research, I believe. FYI I didn't vote it down, but you could flesh your question out a little more with what you're struggling with exactly.

Comment: If I didn't understand someone. I ask then: What do you mean? or something.

Comment: I was explaining to you why someone would down vote your question. No one is down voting you for asking a question, it's HOW you ask the question that is the issue.

Comment: I will never voting -1 for someone.

Comment: @user1531040: The voting system is not just for positive feedback, it's also for a negative feedback. However, stack exchange websites does encourage adding a comment when you downvote, and rightfully so. There is no point of downvoting without explaining the downvote reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a where clause on a foreign key constraint.
However, you can use a regular foreign key constraint and also a check constraint, where your check expression will be if the `CompanyTypeId` is actually 1 for the `CompanyId` that you try to insert into `contract`.

To do that you will need to create a user defined function that will do the actual test and return a value. for example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CheckCompanyType 
(
    @CompanyId int, 
    @AllowdCompanyType int)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RetVal int
    SELECT @RetVal = COUNT(*)
    FROM Company
    WHERE CompanyId = @CompanyId 
    AND CompanyTypeId = @AllowdCompanyType 
    RETURN @RetVal
END
```

And then in your check constraint you should execute this function and check if the returned value is higher then 0 (should probably be 0 or 1 in your case):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.[Contract]
ADD  CONSTRAINT CHK_Contract_Company 
     CHECK (dbo.CheckCompanyType(CompanyId, 1) > 0);
```